# Gerar combinação de partidas por rodada

Tags: javascript, lógica

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Estou conseguindo gerar partidas e exibir na tela. Mas acontence que não pode uma mesma esquipe jogar em uma mesma rodada.

Eu criei uma função `verificarRodada()` para evitar isso, mas ela parece não estar evitando. Alguém ajuda?

```
 function gerarRodadas(arrTimes, arrPartidas)
  {
       qtd_total_partidas = arrPartidas.length;
       qtd_rodadas = (arrTimes.length-1)*2;
       qtd_partidas_por_rodada = arrTimes.length/2;

       arr_pos = new Array(qtd_total_partidas);     
       iniciarArray(arr_pos, qtd_total_partidas);

       for(i=0; i<qtd_rodadas; i++)
       {   
             cond=0;
             while(cond < qtd_partidas_por_rodada)
            {

              rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * qtd_total_partidas);

              if(arr_pos[rand] == 0) 
              {
                if(verificarRodada(i, this.arrRodadas, arrPartidas[rand]))
                {

                    mandante = arrPartidas[rand].mandante;
                    visitante = arrPartidas[rand].visitante;
                    estado = arrPartidas[rand].estado;                  

                    this.arrRodadas.push(new Array(i, mandante, visitante, estado));
                    arr_pos[rand] = 1;    
                    cond++;
                 }
               } 
             }
        }

        this.arrRodadas.forEach(rodada => {
          part = "Rodada : " + (rodada[0]+1) + " - " + rodada[1] + " vs " + rodada[2] + " - " + rodada[3];
          criarElemento("add_partidas", "p", part);

        })     
  }

  function verificarRodada(rodada, rodadas, partida)
  {
     mandante = partida.mandante;
     visitante = partida.visitante;

     rodadas.forEach(item  => {
        if(item[0] == rodada)
        {
          if(item[1] == mandante || item[1] == visitante || item[2] == mandante || item[2]== visitante)
          {
            return false;
          }
        }
     })
     return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Percebi um possível problema na função **verificarRodada**

Em vez de utilizar o forEach, use find

```
  function verificarRodada(rodada, rodadas, partida)
  {
     mandante = partida.mandante;
     visitante = partida.visitante;

     rodadas.find(item  => {
         return (item[0] == rodada) &&
                (item[1] == mandante || item[1] == visitante || item[2] == mandante || item[2]== visitante)
     });
  }
```

O forEach não é parado com return false. Use o **find** ou **every**.

Comment: Continua o mesmo problema. Imprime os jogos, mas esta deixando o mesmo time jogar duas vezes na mesma rodada.